# Single quote in custom query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this procedure for custom paging, search and sort options.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_OrdersPaginated]
@Name         NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,
@OrderNumber       NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,   
@Status            NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,
@OrderBy           NVARCHAR(100)=NULL,
@PageNumber        INT,            
@PageSize          INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #ORDERS       
(       
 [OrderId] Bigint
,[Name] Varchar(100)
,[Status] Varchar(50)
,[CreatedDate] Date   
,[OrderNumber] Varchar(100)
,[UserId] Bigint
,[Amount] Decimal
,RowNumber Bigint IDENTITY(1,1)       
)
DECLARE @intTotal INT
SET @intTotal = @PageSize * @PageNumber
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Where NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Order NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT dbo.[Order].OrderId, [User].Name, dbo.[Order].Status, 
                dbo.[Order].CreatedDate, [Order].OrderNumber, dbo.[User].UserId, 
                dbo.Order.[Amount]
        FROM dbo.[Order] 
        INNER JOIN dbo.User 
        ON dbo.[User].UserId = dbo.[Order].UserId'
SET @Order =' ORDER BY ' +@OrderBy


IF @Name is not null
SET @Where = @Where + ' AND dbo.[User].Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'''
IF @OrderNumber is not null
SET @Where = @Where + ' AND dbo.[Order].OrderNumber LIKE '''+@OrderNumber+'%'''
IF @Status is not null
SET @Where = @Where + ' AND dbo.[Order].[Status] LIKE '''+@Status+'%'''

IF LEN(@Where) > 0
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where)-4)

INSERT INTO #ORDERS
EXECUTE (@sSQL + @Order)

Select [OrderId],[Name],[Status],[CreatedDate],[OrderNumber,[UserId]
,[Amount],RowNumber
From #ORDERS           
WHERE  RowNumber between ((@PageNumber * @PageSize)-(@PageSize- 1)) AND (@PageNumber * @PageSize) 

Declare @TotalRecords Integer             
Declare @TotalPage Integer                         

SELECT @TotalRecords=MAX(RowNumber) from #ORDERS              
if(@TotalRecords is not NULL)             
begin             
if(@TotalRecords%@PageSize = 0)             
begin             
SET @TotalPage = @TotalRecords/@PageSize             
end             
else              
begin             
SET @TotalPage = @TotalRecords/@PageSize + 1             
end             
end             
else             
begin             
set @TotalPage = 1             
end              
Select @TotalPage [TotalPages], @TotalRecords [TotalRecords]
DROP Table #ORDERS
END
```

As you can see one of the Search params is Name. The Procedure works perfectly for all except for Single Quote(') for obvious reason. Example: if I pass O' Brien for name it would fail. Is there any way to handle such single quote values with custom queries on SQL Server?

Comment: Can you show us the way set `@Name` and the way you invoke the sproc after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from not constructing your dynamic SQL in a best-practice manner, which along with making it difficult to construct the correct SQL, is also exposing you to SQL injection attacks.

Essentially, you should never use concatenation when adding parameters to your SQL string. I also use `char(37)` to represent the `%` sign, as this way it isn't necessary to escape it with apostrophes.

So your SQL becomes something like

```
IF @Name is not null
  SET @Where += 'AND Name LIKE char(37)+@Name+char(37)'

IF @OrderNumber is not null
  SET @Where += ' AND OrderNumber LIKE @OrderNumber+char(37)'

IF @Status is not null
  SET @Where += ' AND [Status] LIKE @Status+char(37)'

IF LEN(@Where) > 0
  SET @sSQL += ' WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where)-4)
```

Creating the OrderBy is harder as you cannot parameterise that. if you  absolutely trust the value passed in, then your code is okay, but the safest way would be to have something like an if statement that 
 tests the value passed in and creates the appropriate clause. e.g.

```
IF @OrderBy = 'status'
  SET @Ssql += ' ORDER BY Status'

--Next you need to declare the parameters being included in the dynamic SQL. i'm making up the variable types, as you didn't specify what they were.
declare @params nvarchar(1000) = '@name nvarchar(100), @ordernumber nvarchar(100), @status nvarchar(10)'

--Then you can execute your dynamic SQL, passing to it the parameters provided to your procedure

insert into #temp 
ExeCUTE sp_executesql @sSQL, @params,  @name, @ordernumber, @status
```

One other benefit of constructing dynamic SQL in this manner, rather than concatenating strings, is that SQL Server can actually cache the query plan like it does for non-dynamic SQL and you don't have the performance hit that you get when you use concatenation.

Comment: I changed the procedure as you suggested, but I am getting this exception `Must declare the scalar variable "@Name"`. It is already declared but not sure why this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
IF @Name is not null
BEGIN
   SET @Name = REPLACE(@Name, '''', '''''')
   SET @Where = @Where + ' AND dbo.[User].Name LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%'''
END
```

Comment: After `SET @Where` add `print @Where` and show me the result